# iphone: unable to create URL

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am working with facebook apis

I am trying to fetch attributes of an image with id '105502842870274' for this I tried to create a url like this

```
NSString *firstComponent=@"https://graph.facebook.com/105502842870274?access_token=";
firstComponent=[firstComponent stringByAppendingFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_accessToken]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:firstComponent];
```

but every time url is passes as nil.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or suggest someother way to fetch attributes of an image.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Im also facing this issue, problem seems to lies in stringByAppendingFormat ...append seems to like adds extra stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will resolve your issue. Its html encoding problem.

```
firstComponent = [firstComponent stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

also look: [reference page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845425/spaces-in-a-nsurl-with-variables-doesnt-load)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSString *firstComponent=@"https://graph.facebook.com/105502842870274?access_token=";
firstComponent=[firstComponent stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_accessToken]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:firstComponent];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just doing it too complicated, and it is in your extra code that you made an error.

You used `stringByAppendingFormat` instead of `stringByAppendingString`.

For an even easier solution, just do :

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/105502842870274?access_token=%@", _accessToken]];
```

Or if you want to access the string later :

```
NSString* firstComponent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/105502842870274?access_token=%@", _accessToken]
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:firstComponent];
```