# Launch Nokia HERE Maps iOS via API

Tags: iphone, nokia, launching-application, here-api

Is there a documented API for launching Nokia's HERE Maps iOS app for turn-by-turn navigation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
here-place://lat,lon e.g. here-place://48.866833,2.355411
```

to open Here on a given place.

```
here-route://lat1,lon1,name1/lat2,lon2,name2
```

to start turn by turn navigation from lat1,lon1 to lat2,lon2.

```
here-route:///lat2,lon2,name2
```

to start a turn by turn navigation from the user location to lat2,lon2.

EDIT: It seems that name fields now support URL percent escaping to encode space and other characters (Tested in Here WeGo v2.0.11. Thank you marcel for the head up).

Answer (score 4):

Changed to `here-location://lat,lon,name` in the latest versions (probably 1.2 or so). `name` is optional.

`here-place` and `here-route` give `Couldn't open link` error, so probably syntax changed there. Maybe you can specify addresses there, but it was out of scope of my research.

Comment: here-route works on v2.0.11. I have not rested here-place.

Comment: I can confirm here-location still works as of today.

Answer (score 4):

On HERE WeGo `2.0.20 (537)`:

- Open a URL with a custom `here-route` URL Scheme:

  - `//mylocation/latitude,longitude`
  - `,URLencoded string` as the name of the destination
  - `?ref=<Referrer>` referrer (and can be something like your app or company name)
  - `&m=w` to indicate the routing mode (m=w stands for walk, m=d for drive)

For instance, `here-route://mylocation/37.870090,-122.268150,Downtown%20Berkeley? ref=<Referrer>&m=w` requests a route by foot to a destination in downtown Berkeley by a company called Referrer.

Source: [HERE Developer Mobility On-Demand Technical Solution Paper](https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/aggregated_platform_use_cases_hlp/1.0.0/Mobility%20On-Demand%20v1.0.0%20White%20Paper.pdf) (page 36)

---

I've just tested this and it works fine. The most important bit (at least for me) was that **`/mylocation/` has to be in the URL** for HERE WeGo to start navigation from the user's current location (literally the word `mylocation` has to be there).

You can also use `here-route://sourceLat,sourceLon,sourceOptionalName/destLat,destLon,destOptionalName` if you don't want to navigate from the user's current location.

I also tested `here-location://lat,lon,optionalName` and it works fine in the current (latest, see at the top of this answer) version of HERE WeGo (it used to be `here-place`, but it doesn't work anymore).

Comment: I can confirm `here-location` still works as of today.

Comment: The routing mode parameter (`&m=w`) no longer works. Does anyone know if it's still possible to set it?

Answer (score 1):

URL Scheme for an application can be found in the app's `Info.plist`. In `Info.plist -> URL Types -> URL Schemes -> xxxxx`

Extracting bundle contents from ipa is easy. Rename file from .ipa to .zip and unzip to extract contents. Right click on DownloadedApp.app and show package contents. You will find Info.plist, icons, compressed nibs, executable, etc there.

For Nokia HERE Maps app it is **`nok`**

Answer (score 0):

@FKDev

Basically you can replace spaces with %20 sign. Found on [NSData & NSURL - url with space having problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441106/nsdata-nsurl-url-with-space-having-problem) or [Spaces in a NSURL with variables doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845425/spaces-in-a-nsurl-with-variables-doesnt-load)

I preferred too use internal converters shown in the examples

Xcode sample

```
NSString *sUrl = @"here-route:///52.379189,4.899431,Amsterdam Central
sUrl = [sUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sUrl];
```

C# Sample

```
var sUrl= Uri.EscapeUriString(@"here-route:///52.379189,4.899431,Amsterdam Central");
var url = new NSUrl(sUrl);
```

Both sample will be here-route:///52.379189,4.899431,Amsterdam%20Central