# Nokia here URL scheme for iOS

Tags: ios, url-scheme, here-api

As suggested in this answer ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514532/launch-nokia-here-maps-ios-via-api)), I found out what the Nokia here map URL schemes look like. Unfortunately I have no idea how a link has to look like.

If I open the Link "here-location://" on my iPhone, "here" is opened up and shows an alert that the link could not be opened. How do I have to format the latitude and longitude to show a point of interest on the map?

I know it has to look something like this: "here-location://?lat=xxx&lng=xxx"

Does anybody know it exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Nokia HERE Maps iOS via API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514532/launch-nokia-here-maps-ios-via-api)

Answer (score 8):

Tried all kinds of combinations and finally got it by luck.

iOS URL Scheme for nokia here app location:

here-place://{lat},{lng}

for example: here-place://51.1,11.2